# MVC 5 Compile error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am brand new to MVC and suddenly I get this error whenever I try to build my project, no matter where I start the build.
Unfortunately the error is described in Danish, but this is the line:

```
 Linje 43:     public class _Page_Views_Shared__LoginPartial_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<VinylStore.Models.> {
```

It says identifier expected. This is the path:

```
   C:\users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\d57ebae8\c8c8aa37\App_Web__loginpartial.cshtml.639c3968.jsmx0knu.0.cs
```

I have no idea why this suddenly happened, probably me making a rookie mistake, but does anyone know how to fix this??

All Thoughts are appreciated!

I have not been able to find any information on this error.

EDIT

Sorry, this is the whole source. Might be helpful to a skilled eye.

```
> Linje 1:    #pragma checksum "c:\users\spont\onedrive\dokumenter\visual studio 2015\Projects\VinylStore\VinylStore\Views\Shared\_LoginPartial.cshtml" "{ff1816ec-aa5e-4d10-87f7-6f4963833460}" "518263DAA87E2345C68BEA90D9DE845CCF2C6D7A"
Linje 2:    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Linje 3:    // <auto-generated>
Linje 4:    //     Denne kode blev oprettet ved hjælp af et værktøj.
Linje 5:    //     Runtime-version:4.0.30319.42000
Linje 6:    //
Linje 7:    //     Ændringer af denne fil kan resultere i ukorrekt funktion, og ændringerne mistes, hvis
Linje 8:    //     koden oprettes igen.
Linje 9:    // </auto-generated>
Linje 10:   //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Linje 11:   
Linje 12:   namespace ASP {
Linje 13:       using System;
Linje 14:       using System.Collections.Generic;
Linje 15:       using System.IO;
Linje 16:       using System.Linq;
Linje 17:       using System.Net;
Linje 18:       using System.Web;
Linje 19:       using System.Web.Helpers;
Linje 20:       using System.Web.Security;
Linje 21:       using System.Web.UI;
Linje 22:       using System.Web.WebPages;
Linje 23:       using System.Web.Mvc;
Linje 24:       using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
Linje 25:       using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
Linje 26:       using System.Web.Optimization;
Linje 27:       using System.Web.Routing;
Linje 28:       using VinylStore;
Linje 29:       
Linje 30:       #line 1 "c:\users\spont\onedrive\dokumenter\visual studio 2015\Projects\VinylStore\VinylStore\Views\Shared\_LoginPartial.cshtml"
Linje 31:       using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
Linje 32:       
Linje 33:       #line default
Linje 34:       #line hidden
Linje 35:       
Linje 36:       #line 2 "c:\users\spont\onedrive\dokumenter\visual studio 2015\Projects\VinylStore\VinylStore\Views\Shared\_LoginPartial.cshtml"
Linje 37:       using System.Security.Claims;
Linje 38:       
Linje 39:       #line default
Linje 40:       #line hidden
Linje 41:       
Linje 42:       
Linje 43:       public class _Page_Views_Shared__LoginPartial_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<VinylStore.Models.> {
Linje 44:           
Linje 45:   #line hidden
Linje 46:           
Linje 47:           public _Page_Views_Shared__LoginPartial_cshtml() {
Linje 48:           }
Linje 49:           
Linje 50:           protected ASP.global_asax ApplicationInstance {
Linje 51:               get {
Linje 52:                   return ((ASP.global_asax)(Context.ApplicationInstance));
Linje 53:               }
Linje 54:           }
Linje 55:           
Linje 56:           public override void Execute() {
Linje 57:               
Linje 58:               #line 5 "c:\users\spont\onedrive\dokumenter\visual studio 2015\Projects\VinylStore\VinylStore\Views\Shared\_LoginPartial.cshtml"
Linje 59:    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
Linje 60:               {
Linje 61:                   var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
Linje 62:                   var name = identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.GivenName) ?? identity.GetUserName();
Linje 63:   
Linje 64:                   using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
Linje 65:                   {
Linje 66:                       
Linje 67:               
Linje 68:               #line default
Linje 69:               #line hidden
Linje 70:   BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 476, 23, false);
Linje 71:   
Linje 72:               
Linje 73:               #line 12 "c:\users\spont\onedrive\dokumenter\visual studio 2015\Projects\VinylStore\VinylStore\Views\Shared\_LoginPartial.cshtml"
Linje 74:                  Write(Html.AntiForgeryToken());
Linje 75:   
Linje 76:               
Linje 77:               #line default
Linje 78:               #line hidden
Linje 79:   EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 476, 23, false);
Linje 80:   
Linje 81:               
Linje 82:               #line 12 "c:\users\spont\onedrive\dokumenter\visual studio 2015\Projects\VinylStore\VinylStore\Views\Shared\_LoginPartial.cshtml"
Linje 83:                                               
Linje 84:   
Linje 85:   
Linje 86:               
Linje 87:               #line default
Linje 88:               #line hidden
Linje 89:   BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 503, 11, true);
Linje 90:   
Linje 91:   WriteLiteral("        <ul");
Linje 92:   
Linje 93:   EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 503, 11, true);
Linje 94:   
Linje 95:   BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 514, 36, true);
Linje 96:   
Linje 97:   WriteLiteral(" class=\"nav navbar-nav navbar-right\"");
Linje 98:   
Linje 99:   EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 514, 36, true);
Linje 100:  
Linje 101:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 550, 39, true);
Linje 102:  
Linje 103:  WriteLiteral(">\r\n            <li>\r\n                <a");
Linje 104:  
Linje 105:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 550, 39, true);
Linje 106:  
Linje 107:  WriteAttribute("href", Tuple.Create(" href=\"", 589), Tuple.Create("\"", 632)
Linje 108:              
Linje 109:              #line 16 "c:\users\spont\onedrive\dokumenter\visual studio 2015\Projects\VinylStore\VinylStore\Views\Shared\_LoginPartial.cshtml"
Linje 110:  , Tuple.Create(Tuple.Create("", 596), Tuple.Create<System.Object, System.Int32>(Url.Action("Index", "ShoppingCart")
Linje 111:              
Linje 112:              #line default
Linje 113:              #line hidden
Linje 114:  , 596), false)
Linje 115:  );
Linje 116:  
Linje 117:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 633, 18, true);
Linje 118:  
Linje 119:  WriteLiteral("  id=\"btnMenuCart\"");
Linje 120:  
Linje 121:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 633, 18, true);
Linje 122:  
Linje 123:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 651, 14, true);
Linje 124:  
Linje 125:  WriteLiteral(" role=\"button\"");
Linje 126:  
Linje 127:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 651, 14, true);
Linje 128:  
Linje 129:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 665, 19, true);
Linje 130:  
Linje 131:  WriteLiteral(" class=\"btn btn-md\"");
Linje 132:  
Linje 133:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 665, 19, true);
Linje 134:  
Linje 135:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 684, 28, true);
Linje 136:  
Linje 137:  WriteLiteral(">\r\n                    <span");
Linje 138:  
Linje 139:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 684, 28, true);
Linje 140:  
Linje 141:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 712, 42, true);
Linje 142:  
Linje 143:  WriteLiteral(" class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart\"");
Linje 144:  
Linje 145:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 712, 42, true);
Linje 146:  
Linje 147:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 754, 19, true);
Linje 148:  
Linje 149:  WriteLiteral(" aria-hidden=\"true\"");
Linje 150:  
Linje 151:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 754, 19, true);
Linje 152:  
Linje 153:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 773, 90, true);
Linje 154:  
Linje 155:  WriteLiteral("></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0</a>\r\n            </li>\r\n            <li>\r\n           " +
Linje 156:  "     <div");
Linje 157:  
Linje 158:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 773, 90, true);
Linje 159:  
Linje 160:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 863, 17, true);
Linje 161:  
Linje 162:  WriteLiteral(" class=\"dropdown\"");
Linje 163:  
Linje 164:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 863, 17, true);
Linje 165:  
Linje 166:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 880, 30, true);
Linje 167:  
Linje 168:  WriteLiteral(">\r\n                    <button");
Linje 169:  
Linje 170:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 880, 30, true);
Linje 171:  
Linje 172:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 910, 16, true);
Linje 173:  
Linje 174:  WriteLiteral(" id=\"btnProfile\"");
Linje 175:  
Linje 176:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 910, 16, true);
Linje 177:  
Linje 178:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 926, 28, true);
Linje 179:  
Linje 180:  WriteLiteral(" class=\"btn dropdown-toggle\"");
Linje 181:  
Linje 182:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 926, 28, true);
Linje 183:  
Linje 184:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 954, 14, true);
Linje 185:  
Linje 186:  WriteLiteral(" type=\"button\"");
Linje 187:  
Linje 188:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 954, 14, true);
Linje 189:  
Linje 190:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 968, 23, true);
Linje 191:  
Linje 192:  WriteLiteral(" data-toggle=\"dropdown\"");
Linje 193:  
Linje 194:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 968, 23, true);
Linje 195:  
Linje 196:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 991, 21, true);
Linje 197:  
Linje 198:  WriteLiteral(" aria-haspopup=\"true\"");
Linje 199:  
Linje 200:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 991, 21, true);
Linje 201:  
Linje 202:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1012, 21, true);
Linje 203:  
Linje 204:  WriteLiteral(" aria-expanded=\"true\"");
Linje 205:  
Linje 206:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1012, 21, true);
Linje 207:  
Linje 208:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1033, 3, true);
Linje 209:  
Linje 210:  WriteLiteral(">\r\n");
Linje 211:  
Linje 212:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1033, 3, true);
Linje 213:  
Linje 214:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1036, 24, true);
Linje 215:  
Linje 216:  WriteLiteral("                        ");
Linje 217:  
Linje 218:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1036, 24, true);
Linje 219:  
Linje 220:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1061, 118, false);
Linje 221:  
Linje 222:              
Linje 223:              #line 22 "c:\users\spont\onedrive\dokumenter\visual studio 2015\Projects\VinylStore\VinylStore\Views\Shared\_LoginPartial.cshtml"
Linje 224:                     Write(Html.ActionLink("Hello " + name + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" }));
Linje 225:  
Linje 226:              
Linje 227:              #line default
Linje 228:              #line hidden
Linje 229:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1061, 118, false);
Linje 230:  
Linje 231:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1179, 31, true);
Linje 232:  
Linje 233:  WriteLiteral("\r\n                        <span");
Linje 234:  
Linje 235:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1179, 31, true);
Linje 236:  
Linje 237:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1210, 14, true);
Linje 238:  
Linje 239:  WriteLiteral(" class=\"caret\"");
Linje 240:  
Linje 241:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1210, 14, true);
Linje 242:  
Linje 243:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1224, 64, true);
Linje 244:  
Linje 245:  WriteLiteral("></span>\r\n                    </button>\r\n                    <ul");
Linje 246:  
Linje 247:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1224, 64, true);
Linje 248:  
Linje 249:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1288, 22, true);
Linje 250:  
Linje 251:  WriteLiteral(" class=\"dropdown-menu\"");
Linje 252:  
Linje 253:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1288, 22, true);
Linje 254:  
Linje 255:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1310, 32, true);
Linje 256:  
Linje 257:  WriteLiteral(" aria-labelledby=\"dropdownMenu1\"");
Linje 258:  
Linje 259:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1310, 32, true);
Linje 260:  
Linje 261:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1342, 33, true);
Linje 262:  
Linje 263:  WriteLiteral(">\r\n                        <li><a");
Linje 264:  
Linje 265:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1342, 33, true);
Linje 266:  
Linje 267:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1375, 9, true);
Linje 268:  
Linje 269:  WriteLiteral(" href=\"#\"");
Linje 270:  
Linje 271:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1375, 9, true);
Linje 272:  
Linje 273:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1384, 52, true);
Linje 274:  
Linje 275:  WriteLiteral(">My Profile</a></li>\r\n                        <li><a");
Linje 276:  
Linje 277:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1384, 52, true);
Linje 278:  
Linje 279:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1436, 65, true);
Linje 280:  
Linje 281:  WriteLiteral(" href=\"javascript:document.getElementById(\'logoutForm\').submit()\"");
Linje 282:  
Linje 283:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1436, 65, true);
Linje 284:  
Linje 285:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1501, 86, true);
Linje 286:  
Linje 287:  WriteLiteral(">Log off</a></li>\r\n                    </ul>\r\n                </div>\r\n           " +
Linje 288:  "     ");
Linje 289:  
Linje 290:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1501, 86, true);
Linje 291:  
Linje 292:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1710, 37, true);
Linje 293:  
Linje 294:  WriteLiteral("\r\n            </li>\r\n            <li>");
Linje 295:  
Linje 296:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1710, 37, true);
Linje 297:  
Linje 298:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1830, 22, true);
Linje 299:  
Linje 300:  WriteLiteral("</li>\r\n        </ul>\r\n");
Linje 301:  
Linje 302:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1830, 22, true);
Linje 303:  
Linje 304:              
Linje 305:              #line 34 "c:\users\spont\onedrive\dokumenter\visual studio 2015\Projects\VinylStore\VinylStore\Views\Shared\_LoginPartial.cshtml"
Linje 306:      }
Linje 307:  }
Linje 308:  else
Linje 309:  {
Linje 310:  
Linje 311:              
Linje 312:              #line default
Linje 313:              #line hidden
Linje 314:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1871, 7, true);
Linje 315:  
Linje 316:  WriteLiteral("    <ul");
Linje 317:  
Linje 318:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1871, 7, true);
Linje 319:  
Linje 320:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1878, 36, true);
Linje 321:  
Linje 322:  WriteLiteral(" class=\"nav navbar-nav navbar-right\"");
Linje 323:  
Linje 324:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1878, 36, true);
Linje 325:  
Linje 326:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1914, 15, true);
Linje 327:  
Linje 328:  WriteLiteral(">\r\n        <li>");
Linje 329:  
Linje 330:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1914, 15, true);
Linje 331:  
Linje 332:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1930, 114, false);
Linje 333:  
Linje 334:              
Linje 335:              #line 39 "c:\users\spont\onedrive\dokumenter\visual studio 2015\Projects\VinylStore\VinylStore\Views\Shared\_LoginPartial.cshtml"
Linje 336:         Write(Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" }));
Linje 337:  
Linje 338:              
Linje 339:              #line default
Linje 340:              #line hidden
Linje 341:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 1930, 114, false);
Linje 342:  
Linje 343:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 2044, 19, true);
Linje 344:  
Linje 345:  WriteLiteral("</li>\r\n        <li>");
Linje 346:  
Linje 347:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 2044, 19, true);
Linje 348:  
Linje 349:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 2064, 106, false);
Linje 350:  
Linje 351:              
Linje 352:              #line 40 "c:\users\spont\onedrive\dokumenter\visual studio 2015\Projects\VinylStore\VinylStore\Views\Shared\_LoginPartial.cshtml"
Linje 353:         Write(Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" }));
Linje 354:  
Linje 355:              
Linje 356:              #line default
Linje 357:              #line hidden
Linje 358:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 2064, 106, false);
Linje 359:  
Linje 360:  BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 2170, 18, true);
Linje 361:  
Linje 362:  WriteLiteral("</li>\r\n    </ul>\r\n");
Linje 363:  
Linje 364:  EndContext("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", 2170, 18, true);
Linje 365:  
Linje 366:              
Linje 367:              #line 42 "c:\users\spont\onedrive\dokumenter\visual studio 2015\Projects\VinylStore\VinylStore\Views\Shared\_LoginPartial.cshtml"
Linje 368:  }
Linje 369:  
Linje 370:              
Linje 371:              #line default
Linje 372:              #line hidden
Linje 373:          }
Linje 374:      }
Linje 375:  }
Linje 376:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have passed an incomplete model name to the view:

```
public class _Page_Views_Shared__LoginPartial_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<VinylStore.Models.> {
```

Here, you have a dot at the end of the model name (I am guessing that `VinylStore.Models` is a namespace) you need to specify the name of the model itself in the view like so:

```
@model VinylStore.Models.LoginModel
```

Assuming you had a model called `LoginModel`.

Comment: You are so right. I just noticed. I am not used to the MVC error messages and still panics sometimes. Thank you. Sorry for wasting your time on something so simple, I should have caught that myself. Thanks again.

Comment: @MaDaHoPe no problem